# Saturated ideal has irrelevant ideal as its embedded prime

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let an ideal $I \subset S = k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ defines a subscheme of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$. There is a one-to-one correspondence between the saturated ideals of $S$ and the closed subschemes of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ (Hartshorne exercise II.5.10), so $\text{Proj }S/I = \text{Proj }S/\bar{I}$. But in Eisenbud prop 3.13, if $I = \cap I_i$ is a primary decomposition of $I$, then the saturation $\bar{I} = \cap_{p_i \not\supset S_+} I_i$ where $S_+$ is the irrelevant ideal $(x_0,\dots, x_n)$. Hence $\bar{I}$ is the intersection of primary ideals which associated to primes not containing $S_+$. Therefore, if $I\ne \bar{I}$, we conclude $I$ has an embedded prime $S_+$.

Is this reasoning correct? This comes from my attempt to solve Hartshorne exercise II.8.4(a). Since the irrevelant ideal has no geometric meaning, I don't quite understand what it implies to have $S_+$ as an embedded prime. Any interpretation would be appreciated.

Comment: A more explicit interpretation (not geometric though) is that: (a) first note that $(\bar{I})_l=I_l$ for $l>>0$; (b) for $0\neq a\in \oplus \bar{I}_l/I_l$ homogenous of the highest degree, its annihilator is the irrelevant ideal (when $A=k$).